# Is it possible to configure Azure Event Hubs Capture file names by PartitionKey rather than PartitionId?

Tags: azure-eventhub

When configuring an Azure Event Hub instance for Event Hubs Capture, the following example file name formats are provided, all of which use the `PartitionId` variable in some form.

```
{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}
{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}
{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Minute}/{Second}
```

Is it possible to include the `PartitionKey` in the file name path instead of (or as well as) the `PartitionId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, partition-key is not available for building an AVRO path.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Are there any other variables available other than those shown in the original question?